# Display data in html tables according to the data fetched

Tags: angularjs, json, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a table in hmtl5 wherein I fetch the json data using js and use angular js to loop through the data Following is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
       <div  class="table-bordered table-responsive"  ng-repeat="x in ddata">  
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th>6</th>
        <th>7</th>
        <th>8</th>
        <th>9</th>
        <th>10</th>
        <th>11</th>
        <th>12</th>
        <th>13</th>
        <th>14</th>
        <th>15</th>
        <th>16</th>
        <th>17</th>
        <th>18</th>
        <th>19</th>
        <th>20</th>
        <th>21</th>
        <th>22</th>
        <th>23</th>
        <th>24</th>
        <th>25</th>
        <th>26</th>
        <th>27</th>
        <th>28</th>
        <th>29</th>
        <th>30</th>
        <th>31</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr ng-repeat="i in x"    ng-if='i.month=="Nov"'>
<!--
       <td>Nov</td>
        <td> {{i.day}}</td>
          <td> {{i.month}}</td>
-->

<td>Nov</td>

          <td ng-if='i.day="01"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="02"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="03"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="04"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="05"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="06"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="07"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="08"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="09"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="10"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="11"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="12"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="13"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="14"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="15"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="16"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="17"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="18"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="19"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="20"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="21"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="22"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="23"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="24"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="25"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="26"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="27"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="28"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="29"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="30"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
          <td ng-if='i.day="31"'>{{(i.sgst/1000000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>




        </tr>




    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</div>

</body>
```

Now Ill post some of the json data that I'm fetching

```
{sgst: "5008688.00", month: "Jan", day: "01"}

:
{sgst: "0.00", month: "Aug", day: "01"}

:
{sgst: "5392323.00", month: "Sep", day: "01"}

:
{sgst: "630872.00", month: "Oct", day: "01"}


{sgst: "3258562.00", month: "Nov", day: "01"}


{sgst: "4985962.00", month: "Dec", day: "01"}

:
{sgst: "43685.00", month: "Aug", day: "02"}

:
{sgst: "1591974.00", month: "Sep", day: "02"}

:
{sgst: "3003474.00", month: "Oct", day: "02"}

:
{sgst: "2409776.00", month: "Nov", day: "02"}

:
{sgst: "3567207.00", month: "Dec", day: "02"}

:
{sgst: "31965.00", month: "Aug", day: "03"}

:
{sgst: "236068.00", month: "Sep", day: "03"}

:
{sgst: "6869161.00", month: "Oct", day: "03"}

:
{sgst: "5424188.00", month: "Nov", day: "03"}

:
{sgst: "113323.00", month: "Dec", day: "03"}
```

I want day 01 data to be under column1, day 02 data to be under column 2

With the above code what happens is that for example if the data for day 01 for the month of november is 3258562.00.
3258562.00 gets displayed for all the 31 columns

Day 2 data gets displayed in the entire second row.(same data for all columns) 
and so on

I want the data to be displayed day wise for a particular month

nov day1data day2data day3data ........
dec day1data day2data dat3data ........

Any solution to this problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<tr >

          <td id="monthname">Jan</td>


                          <td ng-repeat="n in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]"> <span ng-if='jd[n]=="0"'>0</span> <span ng-if='jd[n]!="0"'>{{(jd[n]/100000)| currency:"&#8377;"}}</span>  </td>





        </tr>
```

Instead of writing ng-repeat for  I have used it for

the ng-repeat will be repeated 31 times for the month of Jan

similarly I have written 11 more  loops for the remaining 11 months

```
<tr>
<td ng-repeat></td>
</tr>
```

This structure has been repeated 12 times for the corresponding months